# jsTree plugin : button can't work when it was included in each item

Tags: javascript, jstree

I use a tree view plugin which can drag.
I need to add button for each item.
The modals should show up after click button,but it can't work property.
Here's my link:
http://www.sldesign.url.tw/JsTree/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I didn't exactly get the root cause but as a work around what you can do is :

Attach on click handler to memberlist buttons :

```
 $(function () {
                // Init
                $('#data').jstree({
                    'core': {
                        'multiple': false,

                        //"animation" : 0,
                        "check_callback": true,
                        //'force_text' : true,

                        'data': TestData
                    },
                    "plugins": ["contextmenu", "dnd", "state", "types", "wholerow"]
                });

               /*Attach Click function*/
                setTimeout(() => {

                    $('.edit-member').each((index,el) => {
                        $(el).click(() => {
                            $('#exampleModal').show();
                        });
                    });
                }, 1000);
              /*Click function End*/
            });
```

Secondly remove "fade" on the modal popup code
Change this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

to this

```
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: sudhir, but after I "add" a new item the button can't work Orz...

Comment: I try to add

$(".jstree-default-contextmenu li:first-child").on("click", ".edit-member", function () {
  $('#exampleModal').show();
 });

but it can't work.

Comment: I change setTimeout as setInterval, then it works.
Thank you!

Comment: Okay,or you can have it in document ready function. If it helped you can upvote or mark as accepted answer.